# Map a dictionary to lists in dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, mapping

Given a dataframe with columns for `country`, `topic`, `industry`, how would I map a dictionary to each column when the columns consist of lists?

For example, the dictionary for country contains hundreds of mappings for country and region codes:

```
>> cnt_dict = {'AARCT': 'ANTARTICA', 'ABDBI': 'ABU DHABI', 'AFGH': 'AFGHANISTAN' ... 'ZAIRE': 'DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF THE CONGO', 'ZAMBIA': 'ZAMBIA', 'ZIMBAB': 'ZIMBABWE'}
```

The corresponding column in `df` is full of lists of country codes:

```
>>df['country'].head(5)
country
[ANDO, COOKIS, INDOCH]
[IRAN]
[MALAG, BERM, WESTW, USAWI]
[]
[ECU, FALK, OMAN]
```

How would I map `cnt_dic` to `df['country']` to transform every value in each list to its mapped dictionary values so that the output would be (using pseudo code):

```
>> df['country'] = df['country'].map(cnt_dic to lists)
>> df['country'].head(5)
country
[ANDORRA, COOK ISLANDS, INDO-CHINA]
[IRAN]
[MADAGASCAR, BERMUDA, WESTERN WORLD, UNITED STATES WISCONSIN]
[]
[ECUADOR, FALKLAND ISLANDS, OMAN]
```

I tried `df['country'] = df['country'].apply(lambda x: list(map(lambda y:cnt_dic.get(y, None), x)))` but I only get `None` values in all the lists, and nothing else has worked.

Also, if possible, the final dataframe is quite large, so speed matters.

Comment: have you tried `df['country'] = df['country'].apply(lambda x: [cnt_dict.get(i) for i in x])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@trianta2 @DrakeMurdoch
just to be sure I tried to produce an example, and it is working correctly

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'d': [['A', 'B'], ['B', 'C'], ['A']]})
df
        d
0  [A, B]
1  [B, C]
2     [A]
d = {'A':2, 'B':0, 'C':4}
df['k'] = df['d'].apply(lambda x: [d[i] for i in x])

#output
df
        d       k
0  [A, B]  [2, 0]
1  [B, C]  [0, 4]
2     [A]     [2]
```

Comment: So, for some reason, when I do it, it is only filling in the first value in the list, and leaving the rest as `None`. Do you have any clue why this would be the case? For example: `['ARGENTINA', None, None]`

Comment: The only reason I can think of is that you don't have the right key on you dictionary, can you double check?

Comment: Ok, I discovered some whitespace that was screwing it up. But now it works perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your `country` column is a series of lists, so you need to iterate over the elements in each row list, and use the element as the key in `cnt_dict`. @nidabdella's comment does just this. However, lists aren't hashable, so you should have been getting a `TypeError` instead of `None`...

Comment: Even when I use @nidabella's idea, I still get the `None` in all my lists.